# Kubernetes + Jenkins: how to assign all jenkins slave to one specific node

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, jenkins-plugins

In my cluster, I have one node vm1, with label "kubernetes.io/hostname: vm-1". Can I configure to assign all Pod slaves to vm-1 node? I tries to set "Node Selector" in Jenkin > Configuration > cloud but it does not work.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is specify this in the `Deployment` of your jenkins slave with `nodeAffinity`, like so:

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: jenkins-slave
  namespace: ci
  labels:
    app: jenkins
    role: slave
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: jenkins
      role: slave
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: jenkins
        role: slave
    spec:
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
              - matchExpressions:
                  - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
                    operator: In
                    values:
                      - vm-1
```

You can see some examples [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity)

However, I am not sure if `kubernetes.io/hostname` is a valid label to be used when selecting node affinity, maybe you will need to create one, such as `role`, `dedicated` or `type`.

Comment: Thanks, but I am using kubernetes-plugin, so how can configure deployment like that https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin

Comment: Sorry, but I am not familiar with that plugin. From what I can see, there is a `nodeSelector` option in the configuration here: https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#pod-and-container-template-configuration

Comment: Yes, I tried but it does not work. I dont know there is any missing?

Comment: @JackyPhuong did you figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

Use the Kubernetes plugin [yaml syntax](https://github.com/jenkinsci/kubernetes-plugin#using-yaml-to-define-pod-templates) and add `affinity` section as described in https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/